# Trade position via crypto

Tags: pine-script

I want to tell my script, if the symbol i'm on is crypto, use posSize, if it is anything else (stocks, forex etc) and the position size is under 1, then round it up to one and use that, otherwise again, just use positionSize

How is this done please?

```
positionSize = r / sl
    strategy.entry(id="entry", direction=strategy.long, qty=posSize)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `syminfo.type` built-in variable.

Possible values are:

- stock
- futures
- index
- forex
- crypto
- fund
- dr